# Why is not Unity recognizing my digital camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, facetime

I have mixed around with Unity and Vuforia. Im all set and got it to work with an image that spawns 3D objects. My project has been done with my FaceTime Camera on my Macbook pro 2018. Now i want to try and move over to my Digital Camera: Sony AX6300. But when i connect the camera, Unity wont recognize it. I can still only choose FaceTime Cam built in on my Mac. Can anyone in here help out maybe?
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udwn9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit the xml file named webcamprofiles.xml inside vuforiaresource, and add or edit your device camera name...
it works for me

Comment: I see. So there i´ll add my sony camera.. with exact name or ?

Comment: <webcam deviceName="WebCam">
those "WebCam" just change it with the name of the camera device You've been used, in my case, i run devmgmt.msc to check my camera Imaging Device, and look for the name of my camera device